# Facebook Messenger API não responde novos usuários

Tags: api, facebook

Eu tenho um APP no Facebook Developers, um BOT para o Messenger. Ele responde a testers e admins. Mas para novos usuários não. Meu aplicativo já é publico, ja passou pela aprovação. Vi muitos com essa dúvida mas nenhuma resposta sobre o problema.

Comment: Em algum momento você esta recuperando o token do usuário?

Comment: @LucasCosta eu recebo o sender id de todos eles. Recebo a mensagem deles. Porem nao consigo responder. Sera que tenho que obter alguma permissao do usuario? Como faria isso pelo messenger do facebook?

Comment: Eu não testei ainda a api do messenger, perguntei porque a graph api recupera o token do usuário (sim, o usuário já teve que ter permitido o aplicativo de obter informacoes, como likes, posts, etc). Eu já tive um problema com o que você está tendo porque eu recuperava um token de acesso de sistema, não de usuário.

Comment: São essas varições, no caso da graph @GuilhermeIA: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Eu ja entendi o que está acontecendo. Mudou as formas de obter um aplicativo realmente publico no Messenger, vou postar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri qual era o problema, depois de alguns dias pesquisando.
Atualmente naão é so marcar como publico e achar que esta tudo resolvido. E necessario voce dizer quais permissoes voce precisa e o porque de cada uma. Tem que tambem adicionar notas do porque de cada permissao e seguir alguns passos que eles pedem. Depois de preencher tudo e estar de acordo com o que eles pedem, voce manda para revisao. Se eles aceitarem, ai vamos ver o que acontece.